# How to get files from iPhoto

Tags: photos.app, picasa

During my first day with a Mac, I imported some pictures from a SD card into iPhoto. After a few days I have decided not to use iPhoto and switch to Picasa instead.

My question is, how to get my original files from iPhoto. I know I could export them, but I am not sure this will give me the original files.

I am using iPhoto 11 (version 9.3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File -> Export and set the **Kind** to *Original*

This will yield an exact copy of the photo you imported.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the imported files on your PC in your home folder => Pictures => iPhoto Library. You will have to control (right) click on it and select "Show Package Contents" in order to see the files otherwise it will just open iPhoto.

You can also right click on a picture within iPhoto and select "Show File" to view the file.